# Chrome browser opens extra tabs on startup

Tags: google-chrome, tabs

I have chrome setup to automatically open a number of pinned tabs on startup.
(GMail, Calendar, Drive, G+, Tasks, Keep)

This works, but I also get a few extra tabs opening randomly each time I start. Sometimes these are calendar tabs, sometimes gmail, or other google service related tabs.

This happens on multiple machines. Not always exactly the same extra tabs, and not always the same number of extra tabs. The extra tabs are regular tabs, not pinned. 
I've reset my startup pages in the "On-startup" section in the settings tab, multiple times and on multiple machines, but it doesn't seem to help.

Any ideas on how to diagnose/fix this?

Chrome Version 30.0.1599.114
Operating System: Linux

Update - 
The extra tabs are:
Calendar, Drive , Google+, Keep, so tabs in the same order as my pinned tabs, but missing GMail and the Task tabs this time.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, thus how I found this page. I think I have fixed it by changing my settings under 'On Startup' to 'Continue where I left off' from 'Open a specific page or set of pages'. I don't remember setting that at any point, I've always preferred to continue where I left off, but somehow it got set. Seems to have fixed the issue at work, now to confirm when I get home.